# is there a solution for position:fixed in old mobile browser

Tags: css-position

many old mobile brwoser do not support position:fixed, I tried writing a sloution myself,it works, but not smooth enough.

I googled, no luck for now.

so I would like to know if there is "smooth" solution for this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be better to mention the browsers that you have problems with. for example I assume you have problems with IE6. I will try to answer your question according to my assumptions. So the 100% height on the body and html stuff is in case you want to do fixed positioning along the bottom edge of the browser window.

like so:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
body #fixedElement {
   position:fixed !important;
   position: absolute; /*ie6 and above*/
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
#page-wrap {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font: 16px/2 Georgia, Serif;
}
```

hope this will help please also check this site when having problems related to CSS

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-positioning-in-ie-6/